# checking if key exists in hashmap where the key is a nested hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following HashMap:

```
private HashMap<HashMap<Integer,String>,ArrayList<String>> unique_schemas = new HashMap<HashMap<Integer,String>,ArrayList<String>>();
```

I am having no problems adding entries to it or printing out its contents but I'm not sure how to check for an existing entry.

I have tried:

```
//create temp HashMap to check against
HashMap<Integer,String> mapkey = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
//populate it with the values to check for
mapkey.put(parentId,text);
if (unique_schemas.containsKey(mapkey.get(0))) {
    //do whatever when the entry exists
}
```

This isn't working, I know it's wrong somewhere but I'm at a loss. Can anyone shed some light on my problem?

Comment: what's not working? how does it behave?

Comment: `unique_schemas` key is a `HashMap<Integer,String>`, and you are comparing it between `mapkey.get(0)` which is a `String`.

Comment: @bigdestroyer that makes sense, I'm not sure how the syntax of the comparison should be written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the check to:

```
//create temp HashMap to check against
HashMap<Integer,String> mapkey = new HashMap<Integer,String>();
//populate it with the values to check for
mapkey.put(parentId,text);
if (unique_schemas.containsKey(mapkey)) {
    //do whatever when the entry exists
}
```

If you are sure that there is just one  pair in the map you could also allocate just 1 element to the map:

```
private HashMap<HashMap<Integer,String>,ArrayList<String>> unique_schemas = new HashMap<HashMap<Integer,String>,ArrayList<String>>(1);
```

Comment: Ah so simple, I was running around in circles! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

If your key is of type `HashMap<Integer, String>` you can't query the map with a key of type `String` which `unique_schemas.containsKey(mapkey.get(0))` would do, since `mapKey.get(0)` would return the string value for key 0, if it exists.

So try `unique_schemas.containsKey(mapkey)` instead, to use the entire map as a key, as you specified it.

Btw, I'd most probably refactor that whole construct, since using a map as a key seems quite odd to me. Can the key *really* contain multiple combinations of id and text? Would it be a problem to have a `Map<KeyClass, List<String>>` instead, where `KeyClass` would look like this:

```
class KeyClass {
  Integer id;
  String text;

  public int hashCode() { ... }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
}
```

Note that this is just a stub and you'd need to expand that, especially the implementation of `hashCode()` and `equals()`.